# select multiple elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery in my website to change my website page. If I select one page in my website I want to hide my current page and load the selected page in my website. But when I click #work on page my #home page is hidden, but my work page is not loading. Can any one please solve my issue?

This is my jquery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#work").click(function(){
       $("#home").fadeOut("slow");
       $("#work").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: How can you even click at #work if it's hidden from the start?

Comment: @Anto: Why did you not post a full example of your code?

Comment: @amir i try like that but its also not working...

Comment: Why are you just not using standard navigation?

Comment: @reporter This is my full code..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try updated fiddle. it hides clicked and shows hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home").click(function(){
       $("#home").fadeOut("slow");
       $("#work").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
div { width: 300px; heigth: 100px; }
div#home { background-color: yellow; }
div#work { background-color: red; display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">HOME PAGE</div>
<div id="work">WORK PAGE</div>
```

Comment: Not sure the visible moving up of the Work Page would be desirable behaviour.

Comment: We do not know requirenments :)